# Unable to authorise to Sonar at CloudBees API

Tags: sonarqube, cloudbees

I am trying to connect to the sonar API at Cloudbees with CURL. I've tried the following URL (with my CloudBees mailaddress and password filled in):

curl -u : https://.sonar.cloudbees.com/api/resources

The username is in the format of a mailaddress (me@mydomain.com)

The secret is my CloudBees password and tried also the API Key and API Password from CloudBees, but that also doesn't seem to work.

The cloudbeesname is my domainname which I use to connect to the Sonar Dashboard.

The URL seems to be OK, because it works when I enter it in a browser where I am already logged in.

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Have you already set up a user in https://youraccountname.sonar.cloudbees.com/users ?

Comment: Please raise a support ticket for this issue. Currently there is only one username/password combo (unique per customer) that will work for Basic Authentication due to workarounds that were added so that automated DEV@cloud Jenkins integration worked.